# SSAS Calculated Member for measures that have the same Dimension

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I am trying to create a calculated measure that subtracts measures that are in different groups, but only if they have the same dimension member whatever that may be. (edit - essentially exclude UnknownMember numbers in the subtraction)

I have tried using Scope:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[CalcField] as NULL;

SCOPE([Dimension1].[DimensionField1].MEMBERS);
    [Measures].[CalcField] = [Measures].[a] - [Measures].[b];
END SCOPE;
```

I have also tried using a Tuple without success:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[CalcField]
AS ([Measures].[a] - [Measures].[b], [Dimension1].[DimensionField1]);
```

But I think there is something fundamental that I am missing

**Edit**

col a b dimension
1. 9 0 x
2. 0 2 x
3. 1 5 null

If you aggregate those rows I want the answer 7 not 5

Using a simple CASE WHEN works if the dimensions in use, but otherwise it blindly subtracts everything again

```
CASE 
  WHEN [Dimension1].[DimensionField1] IS [Dimension1].[DimensionField1].UnknownMember THEN 0 
  ELSE [Measures].[a] - [Measures].[b]
END
```

Using Aggregate works at the high level, but then when I use the Dimension I get no per member results

```
Aggregate(
  EXCEPT(
    [Dimension1].[DimensionField1].Members, {[Dimension1].[DimensionField1].UnknownMember, [Dimension1].[DimensionField1].[All]}
  ),[Measures].[a]) 
- 
Aggregate(
  EXCEPT(
    [Dimension1].[DimensionField1].Members, {[Dimension1].[DimensionField1].UnknownMember, [Dimension1].[DimensionField1].[All]}
  ),[Measures].[b])
```

**Workaround Solution**
I am sorry if I was not clear on my problem, but I have ended up solving this problem by putting the data I need in at the ETL stage rather than calculating it in the Cube

Comment: What is the exact problem? Is there an error message?

Comment: Please provide example based on Adventure Works - we will find the solution for you.

Comment: @DanielHanczyc - Giving an example based on AW could be a daunting task in many cases. On SO, you will find that most of the questions ON SQL or MDX, are not based on AW.

Comment: I am designing the calculated column in SSAS, there is no error, it is just blindly subtracting b from a regardless of the dimensions.  
I want it to only subtract b from a where both measures have the same dimension value.  
Perhaps what I need is it to only subtract if it is not an unknown value during the aggregations, I am not sure.

Comment: I am not getting you - "where both measures have the same dimension value"??

Comment: I edited the question, check the bottom part @Sourav_Agasti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try either Summing or Aggregating your second snippet?

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[CalcField]
AS 
 Sum(
    [Measures].[a] - [Measures].[b], 
    [Dimension1].[DimensionField1]
 );

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[CalcField]
AS 
 Aggregate(
    [Measures].[a] - [Measures].[b], 
    [Dimension1].[DimensionField1]
 );
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to match the documentation of how [Sum works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145484(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Using Aggregate(EXCEPT([Dimension1].[DimensionField1].Members, {[Dimension1].[DimensionField1].UnknownMember, [Dimension1].[DimensionField1].[All]}),[Measures].[a]) - Aggregate(EXCEPT([Dimension1].[DimensionField1].Members, {[Dimension1].[DimensionField1].UnknownMember, [Dimension1].[DimensionField1].[All]}),[Measures].[b]) almost works except then I can't use the Dimension in later selects

Answer (score 0):

```
With Member [Measures].[CalcField] as   [Measures].[a] - [Measures].[b]

Select [Measures].[CalcField]
on columns,
[Dimension1].[DimensionField1].MEMBERS    
on rows 

from [cube]
```